# Media Recorder setMaxFileSize problem

Tags: android, video, record

I have a problem trying to set the max file size when recording video.  The documentation for `recorder.setMaxFileSize(long filesize_in_bytes)` says long variable type for the argument. I have a method that returns the free space in long value.  When I try to set this long variable as the argument it fails every time.

Free Space Method

```
public long freeSpace(){
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long free = (long)stat.getBlockSize() *(long)stat.getBlockCount();
Log.w("FREESPACE METHOD", "Free space on SD card: "+free);
return free;
}
```

Excerpt from the media recorder method

```
long spaceFree = freeSpace();
recorder.setblahblah
recorder.setMaxFileSize(spaceFree);  //Fails right here.
```

Logcat

```
05-31 00:30:28.201: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(17697): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setMaxFileSize failed.
```

However if is do this `recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000L);` it works.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  I forgot that the FAT file system has a maximum file size of 4 GB.  So if you use a large card like so many users have now, there may be over 4GB of free space.  This is a file system limitation.

There is also another stack overflow answer on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793471/android-what-is-mediarecorders-maximum-maxfilesize)

Answer (score 1):

Use `getAvailableBlocks()` instead of `getBlockCount()`. Looks like you're getting the total size of the SD Card, not the free space.

Comment: You are correct.  That fixes the variable to be just the free space.  The value returned is 29641244672 which is well within the long value range.  It still fails.

Comment: You're probably bumping into the 4GB file size limit problem on FAT32 systems. I don't know if there's a good Android-supported way around it, but if you don't need anything bigger than that, try setting it just under 4GB and see if that works.

Comment: My solution was to check the free space, compare it to the max file size (4000000000) and send whichever is smaller.